# ATX case with far holes for 3.5' HDD

Tags: hard-disk, case, sata

I am searching for a ATX case with proper mouting holes for the new high-capacity 3.5' HDDs. (seagate archive 8TB).

All atx cases have mounting holes only for middle screws and cannot properly mount these HDDs with 4 screws.

I am not interested in alternative mounting like sleds,caddies,rubber bands etc.

I need at least 6 mounting positions for 6 HDDs

[image: hdd without middle holes for screws]

**Can anyone recommend an ATX case which has proper holes for screws for 6 drives?**

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have any other requirements at all?

Comment: no, i think there are not many cases anyway that i could choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose Fractal Design Define XL R2, the drive caddies have correct mounting holes.